# What's the fast way select distinct orderID in this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Suppose I have some `orderID` in SQL Server. Every `orderID` may have multiple `timestamps`, which can be null. What's the fast way to find distinct `orderID` which

- All have non-null `timestamps`
- The last `timestamps` is in yesterday

**Example:**

Today is  2018-02-08, and data as below, the result should be OrderID 11.

```
OrderID     | Timestamp
------------+-------------------------
   11       | 2018-02-07 10:08:52.740    
   11       | 2018-02-06 10:08:52.740    
   22       | 2018-02-03 10:08:52.740    
   22       | 2018-02-04 10:08:52.740    
   33       | 2018-02-07 10:08:52.740    
   33       | NULL
```

PS: this table has about one billion records. And each `orderID` has about 3~4 timestamps.

Comment: Is it possible to have a timestamp in future?

Comment: @SalmanA No. The timestamp is NULL or some time before now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the straight-forward solution is to use GROUP BY/HAVING/MIN/MAX, you need to use WHERE when you're dealing with billion rows:

1. Find rows WHERE timestamp is newer than today - 1
2. Group them and find rows HAVING maximum less than today (this ensures that most recent row is yesterday and not today)
3. For resulting order ids check if their COUNT all = COUNT not null timestamps

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM testdata
    WHERE Timestamp >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 AS DATE)
    GROUP BY OrderID
    HAVING MAX(Timestamp) < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
)
SELECT testdata.OrderID
FROM cte
INNER JOIN testdata ON cte.OrderID = testdata.OrderID
GROUP BY testdata.OrderID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(Timestamp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This sql is takes about 1 sec on billions of records.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `group by` and `having`:

```
select orderid
from t
group by orderid
having count(timestamp) = count(*) and  -- no NULLs
       max(timestamp) >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and
       max(timestamp) < cast(getdate() as date);
```

It might be slightly faster if you move some of the logic to the `where` clause.  This works because you only really care about `NULL` timestamps and those that were yesterday:

```
select orderid
from t
where timestamp is null or
      (timestamp >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and
       timestamp < cast(getdate() as date)
      )
group by orderid
having count(timestamp) = count(*) and  -- no NULLs
       max(timestamp) is not null;
```

Filtering before aggregation can speed the query.

Comment: Thank you sir. May I ask how to count the orderID satisfied above limitations? I tried add `count(orderID)` but no luck.

Comment: A special case would be having a row on todays date (say you have a row with 1AM and it is 2AM); you've already excluded such rows.

Comment: @user27149 . . . Use the above queries as a subquery or CTE and use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much. This works.  The first one take about 3.5 seconds. And the second one takes about 2 seconds. Both are pretty awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can also give this query a try:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT OrderID, 
           FIRST_VALUE(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID
                                        ORDER BY CASE 
                                                    WHEN Timestamp IS NULL THEN 0
                                                    ELSE 1
                                                 END, Timestamp DESC) AS first_timestamp
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT DISTINCT OrderID
FROM CTE 
WHERE  first_timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND
       first_timestamp < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f6f7/8)

**Edit:**

Assuming there are no future dates you can alternatively to the queries using `GROUP BY` use the following query with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderID
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE Timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND

      -- Exclude OrderID slices that contain at least one `NULL` Timestamp
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS x
                  WHERE x.OrderID = t.OrderID AND
                        x.Timestamp IS NULL)

      AND 

      -- Exclude OrderID slices with today's date, or any other future date,
      -- as last Timestamp 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS x
                  WHERE x.OrderID = t.OrderID AND
                        Timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f6f7/11)

Comment: Thanks you sir. Seems the data base does not reponse..`Message:Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Comment: @user27149 Can you try the second query I posted to see if it is any better than the previous one?

Comment: I tried. It takes about 1 second. But seems retrieve some records I don't need.

Comment: @user27149 Can you give me an example of one of these records?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164757/discussion-between-giorgos-betsos-and-user27149).

Comment: It  works perfect. It took about 1 seconds. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct(orderId) from Table 
where 
(day(timestamp)=day(DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))
and month(timestamp)=month(DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))
and year(timestamp)=year(DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))
) and orderid not in (select distinct(orderid) where timestamp is null)
```

This will return you all order ids that happened yesterday
edit 
only the ones that does not have a single null value on it

I added the

```
and orderid not in (select distinct(orderid) where timestamp is null)
```

This will select all the orderids that have a null value on it .
Therefore I exclude them

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Dont know . From his explanation this is what i thought. I am not sure

Comment: @AlexandreCalvario  Thank you. I have some tests. This sql can not filter all NULL values...

Comment: I edited it . You want the null values to apear as distinct order ids ?
Or want only the order ids that only have null values on it

Comment: @AlexandreCalvario No. I want all non-null timestamp

Comment: The OP wants to *exclude* `OrderID` slices that contain *at least one* null `Timestamp` value.

Comment: if you could add more values to the example I would understand better.

Comment: @AlexandreCalvario Seems it takes more records I don't need... I can not figure out where is wrong.. Thank you!